# New preg-repleace for youtube

Tags: php, api, download, youtube

Welcome,

I notice that Youtube make some changes into their website code.

Anyone have idea how make it working today ?

That's my script (don't work anymore)

```
preg_match('/"video_id": "(.*?)"/', $page, $match);
$var_id = $match[1];

preg_match('/"t": "(.*?)"/', $page, $match);
$var_t = $match[1];
```

Look at source of example Youtube video page:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w_J27GxPNM0  (yes i like that song very much)

Now the t variable can be found under

```
<script>
  (function() {
   var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false;
```

I dont paste full because it's very long.

Regards

Comment: Verified link - this is not a rickroll.

Comment: Yes, that's a goth song.

We looking for mystic "t" variable. It's generated randomly and working only for requesting IP address.

So, we downloading website where video player is loaded and we getting that "t" variable. But now they changed place of his location. I don't understand how work that "preg_match".  My question is if someone can rewrite it to extract "t".

Please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just looking at it, it seems that this should work easily enough:

```
pregmatch('/&video_id=([a-zA-Z0-9-%_]*)&/', $page, $match);
$var_id = $match[1];

pregmatch('/&t=([a-zA-Z0-9-%_]*)&/', $page, $match);
$var_t = $match[1];
```

By the way, if you want to be able to do this yourself, it's quite easy. You just need to learn how to use something called a regex. This website is particularly helpful: http://regular-expressions.info/